# Changing the background image of an email

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

**Scenario:** I am trying to create a code to send an email every time a macro is finished with VBA. I got a sample from here [Setting a background image using HTML in an outlook email using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890800/setting-a-background-image-using-html-in-an-outlook-email-using-excel-vba) in the first answer.

**Problem:** I made some slight modifications to this sample but now, when I send the mail it comes with a title but otherwise completely empty (no image and no text).

**Obs:** No error happens, and execution of code goes smoothly.

**Question:** Any idea on what might be happening?

**Code:** This is what I am currently using (btw, the image to be used as background is in the same folder as the macro file).

```
Private Sub mailer2()
Dim oApp, oMail As Object, MyHTML As String, WB As Workbook, FileName As String, BodyText As String, MyText As String
Dim username As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileName = ArchiveFolder & ArchiveFileName

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    username = InputBox("Please write your E-mail")

    MyText = "Greetings" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Your Macro has concluded." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please attend to terminal AFAP"

    MyHTML = "<body background=""cid:Doge.jpg""; center top no-repeat;"

    MyHTML = MyHTML & vbCrLf & "<p style=""font-size:30px;font-weight:Bold;color:rgb(100%,100%,100%)"">" & MyText & "</p>"

    With oMail
        .To = username
        .Subject = "Automated message, please do not answer"
        .HTMLBody = MyHTML
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color in CSS is making your text invisible, you should change the following:

```
color:rgb(100%,100%,100%)
```

Probably to an RGB color without using the percentages, as this seems to apply opacity, and 100% means invisible. If you replace the line above with the one below it should work as expected:

```
color:rgb(100,100,100)
```

Comment: indeed, that solves the text problem, but the image is still missing for some reason...

Comment: @DGMS89 I would try using an absolute path for the image.